# Some UI controls positioned offscreen while simulating app

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working with XCode (Swift) and am having trouble seeing all my controls on the simulator.

[image: This is the simulator view]

[image: This is the XCode view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simulator is launched in a full-scale mode for iPhone 6s Plus. Phone's resolution is too high to display full-size on regular Mac's display. Just go to Simulator Menu > Window > Scale and select 50% to see full-size iPhone screen.

PS: you can also just scroll with a mouse to see all contents of the simulated device screen.

Comment: Parametr! I greatly appreciate your answer. In the future if I become a billionare I'll gladly hand out a million to you. THANKS!